# What is the best Algorithm to decrease the connectivity of a graph by removing a single node?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Given the following undirected graph:

> **no. of nodes:** 7
>   **no. of edges:** 6
>
> **Edges:**
>
> (0 1)
>   (1 2)
>   (2 3)
>   (2 4)
>   (4 5)
>   (4 6)

As you see this graph is one connected component and any node is reachable from any other node. I want to detect the best node to remove such that the resulting graph has the lowest connectivity (maximum number of pairs of nodes that cannot reach other). In this case the best node is 2 as it will result in 3 components (0,1), (3), (4,5,6) and the number of pairs that cannot reach each other are 11.

So what is the best algorithm to detect this node?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Note that for many graphs there will not be a single node that will decrease connectivity. I guess in this case the algorithm should pick a random node? Or a minimum set of nodes that will decrease connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Betweenness centrality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) is a measure of how many shortest paths in a graph go through a specific node (or edge). This is often used in clustering to select the edges that by being removed disconnect the graph most. It sounds very similar to what you want to do.

There are a number of algorithms to calculate betweenness centrality for every node in a graph, such as [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) or Brandes’ Algorithm. Once you have the betweenness centrality for all nodes (make sure to use the node variety of an algorithm, not the edge one) you should pick the node with the highest value, and remove that from the graph.

Comment: thank you so much i think this answer is very helpful and i will search about Betweenness centrality right now.

Comment: but there's a problem maximum number of nodes are 10000 so that minimum complexity in those algorithms with unweighted graph is O(V*E) which is very big

Comment: If you need to do better than that you might have to accept something approximate, as those algorithms are already highly optimised. There are a number of papers on approximating betweenness centrality that you can find with a quick google. I suspect that this is a current research area with no clear conclusions yet, but you can probably find something that will suit.